# Add sprites over a circular CGPath Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, geometry, cgpath

**How can I spawn a sprite repeatedly over the coordinates of a circular path?**

So I have a circular path and I want the sprite to appear every 30º for example (so in that case I would end up having the same sprite 12 times). The problem is that it doesn't matter what I do I cant get it to do so. Recently I found an article were it was shown how to do a clock, I used that sample code but I'm still stuck, I don't know what to replace drawRect for or if I have any other errors.
I would appreciate any help.

```
import SpriteKit
import UIKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

        func degree2radian(a:CGFloat)->CGFloat {
            let b = CGFloat(M_PI) * a/180
            return b
        }


    func circleCircumferencePoints(sides:Int,x:CGFloat,y:CGFloat,radius:CGFloat,adjustment:CGFloat=0)->[CGPoint] {
        let angle = degree2radian(360/CGFloat(sides))
        let cx = x
        let cy = y
        let r  = radius
        var i = sides
        var points = [CGPoint]()
        while points.count <= sides {
            let xpo = cx - r * cos(angle * CGFloat(i)+degree2radian(adjustment))
            let ypo = cy - r * sin(angle * CGFloat(i)+degree2radian(adjustment))
            points.append(CGPoint(x: xpo, y: ypo))
            i--;
        }
        return points
    }

    func pointsLocation(#x:CGFloat, #y:CGFloat, #radius:CGFloat, #sides:Int) {
        let points = circleCircumferencePoints(sides,x,y,radius)
        let path = CGPathCreateMutable()


        for p in enumerate(points) {


            CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, p.element.x, p.element.y)
            let blueDot = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "arrow.png")
            blueDot.position.x = p.element.x
            blueDot.position.y = p.element.y
            addChild(blueDot)
            CGPathCloseSubpath(path)

    class View: UIView {


        override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)


            let rad = CGRectGetWidth(rect)/3.5

            pointsLocation(x: CGRectGetMidX(rect), y: CGRectGetMidY(rect), radius: rad, sides: 8)


    }




override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

        }

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and it works.

Comment: did you changed anything?, it displays 9 errors on mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code has a lot of syntax errors. That's why it doesn't work. After correcting the errors, the logic you used works.

```
class GameScene: SKScene,SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        pointsLocation(x: 100, y: 100, radius: 50, sides: 12)
    }

    func degree2radian(a:CGFloat)->CGFloat {
        let b = CGFloat(M_PI) * a/180
        return b
    }

    func circleCircumferencePoints(sides:Int,x:CGFloat,y:CGFloat,radius:CGFloat,adjustment:CGFloat=0)->[CGPoint] {
        let angle = degree2radian(360/CGFloat(sides))
        let cx = x
        let cy = y
        let r  = radius
        var i = sides
        var points = [CGPoint]()
        while points.count <= sides {
            let xpo = cx - r * cos(angle * CGFloat(i)+degree2radian(adjustment))
            let ypo = cy - r * sin(angle * CGFloat(i)+degree2radian(adjustment))
            points.append(CGPoint(x: xpo, y: ypo))
            i--;
        }
        return points
    }



    func pointsLocation(#x:CGFloat, y:CGFloat, radius:CGFloat, sides:Int) {
        let points = circleCircumferencePoints(sides,x: x,y: y,radius: radius)
        let path = CGPathCreateMutable()


        for p in enumerate(points) {

            let blueDot = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "arrow.png")
            blueDot.position.x = p.element.x
            blueDot.position.y = p.element.y
            addChild(blueDot)

        }
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */

    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }

}
```

Comment: Why is the line "let path = CGPathCreateMutable()" necessary if the path is never used?

Comment: if it's never used, the variable may not be necessary. As i pointed out in my answer, I just corrected his syntax errors not his logic.